# PostrgreSQL not portforwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

Im having an ubuntu server 16.04 that i have installed postgresql server onto with ufw but even after allowing the port 5432 and as well as checking the conf for postgresql.

I even tried follow multiple guides to check if it was open but no.

And we cant figure out why its not open even tho postgreSQL is listet on localhost with the original port

Comment: listen on localhost? so only localhost can access it is normal?

Comment: no i've tried with 0.0.0.0, the public ip, and 127.0.0.1 and none of the work